# Kotlin - cant run "hello world" in intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, kotlin

I am trying to configure Kotlin project by the maven instructions from here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html#KotlinBuildTools-Maven in intellij.
The pom.xml seems to be configured automatically by intellij but I keep getting the error "kotlin not configured" for my hello world file.
The intellij compiler has the error: "Kotlin: Unresolved reference: println".
I am using intellij 15.0.3 and kotlin 1.0.0

Answer (score 4):

found the answer here: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/intellij-kotlin-project-screw-up/597

It seems the project was broken somehow. intellij suggested a fix in project structure that fix the issue.